# Calculate $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},e_i))$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Give an example of a two-fold cover $(\tilde{X},p)$ of figure eight.
For those examples choose a basepoint $e$ and a base point $e_i\in \tilde{X}$ and calculate $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},e_i))$

**My attempt:**

I have drawn the two examples in the next two pictures. I know that both $(p_i)_*$ are injective maps. I think I read a paper that if in the covering space of figure-eight[image] one edge covers a loop then it is regular.( I might be wrong here). In that logic, the first one should be regular.

One very intuition: in the first picture we have two whole loops of B so this would be one to one map and hence $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},e_i))=2\Bbb Z \star \Bbb Z$ and in the second picture there is no whole loop so in each part there are two 2-1 maps, then $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},e_i))=2\Bbb Z \star 2\Bbb Z$.

**I suddenly observe that I wrote the left-hand side pic as fig 1 but forgot to mention that the right-hand side pic is fig 2.**

Please help me by guiding how to calculate these problems and if the method is not at least tell me the answers in the comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Full disclosure! The first definition I gave for regular covering spaces is incorrect. (I've starred the incorrect portion.) Although, the covering space that we've constructed using a covering space action *is* regular. My bad!

A few things to note:

****Incorrect portion:

1. A covering space is **regular** if and only if it's deck transformation group is normal. (There are other equivalent definitions. You should see [Hatcher](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) for more details.)****

The correct portion:

1. A covering space is **regular** if and only if the action of the deck transformation group is transitive.

You're trying to construct a *two*-fold cover. Naturally, the cardinality of the deck transformation group of your covering space should be two. Which groups *or* group has a cardinality of two?

2. I like the first picture a lot! You're on the right track. Consider embedding that triple-8 space into the $x$-$y$ plane of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the following way:

[image]

Note that the embedded space has 180-degree rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ *acts* on the triple-8 space by a rotation angle of 180 degrees about this axis. That is, the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ identifies two points on the triple-8 space if and only if they're related by a 180 degree rotation.

In fact, this action of a group on a topological space describes a **covering space action**. See Hatcher again to fill in the details. The fundamental group of the covering space given by this covering space action is precisely $2\mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z}$---just as you calculated. You just need to argue that the covering space that me and you have constructed *is* a covering space by chasing the definitions in Hatcher (i.e. look up covering space action).