# Covering spaces finding $p_*\pi_1(\tilde{X})$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am currently studying for a qualifying exam covering point set and algebraic topology and am struggling with some covering space theory. Let $p: \widetilde{X} \to X$ be a covering space. I wanted to practice computing $p_*(\pi_1(\widetilde{X}))$, so I referenced the table of covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$ in Hatcher. He said the fundamental groups can also be interpreted as generators of $p_*(\pi_1(\widetilde{X}))$. If that's the case, I'm unsure of the difference between $p_* \pi_1(\widetilde{X}))$ and $\pi_1 (\widetilde{X})$.

I saw this post: [Calculate $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},e_i))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727331/calculate-p-pi-1-tildex-e-i) and got $\langle a ,b | a^2, b^2\rangle$ for the second covering space by tracing out the inner $a^2$ loop and the outer $b^2$ loop, but isn't this also how you'd compute $\pi_1(\widetilde{X})$?

In class, we proved that $p_*(\pi_1(\widetilde{X}))$ is the set of homotopy classes of loops that lift to loops and that it's a subgroup of $\pi_1(\widetilde{X})$, so maybe I'm missing something with the lifting. Can someone please help explain the difference between computing $p_* \pi_1(\widetilde{X}))$ and $\pi_1 (\widetilde{X})$?

Comment: $p_{\ast}$ is always injective so they're canonically isomorphic. But "calculate $p_{\ast}(\pi_1)$" presumably means to calculate it as a subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$ which is more information than just the abstract group.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I'm struggling to see how injectivity implies canonically isomorphic.

Comment: The isomorphism is canonical in the sense that the covering map witnesses the isomorphism when passing to the fundamental group